# How to upgrade bluelinelabs/Conductor version 3.1.4 from version 3.0.0

Tags: android, conductor, autodispose

I'm trying to migrate from version **3.0.0** that used `conductor-rxlifecycle` to version **3.1.4** that is using `conductor-archlifecycle` and `conductor-autodispose`.

my current code has extension functions that binds to the lifecycle - and I'm trying to understand what is the code change needed to adjust it to archlifecycle and auto-dispose.

I would appreciate some help here - couldn't figure it out from the demo code.

[`conductor-archlifecycle` demo](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor/blob/924e4bebfabb8ebaa2f1c3d19bc0f061bc2f2ef8/demo/src/main/java/com/bluelinelabs/conductor/demo/controllers/ArchLifecycleController.kt)

[`conductor-autodispose` demo](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor/blob/94c817bbd903462f06f277735909e39896154696/demo/src/main/java/com/bluelinelabs/conductor/demo/controllers/AutodisposeController.kt)

```
protected fun <C : RxController> Completable.bindToController(controller: C): Completable =
    observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).compose(controller.bindToLifecycle<Any>())

protected fun <C : RxController> Completable.bindUntil(controller: C, event: ControllerEvent): Completable =
    observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).compose(controller.bindUntilEvent<Any>(event))
```

I assume that the controller type should be `LifecycleController` instead of `RxController`, but I don't understand what is the replacement of `bindToLifecycle`

I opened [this issue](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor/issues/668) , but I'm trying to get some help here as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the change I did to my code to match the new Conductor version:

The 2 functions above were replaced by this function:

```
    fun Completable.autoDisposable(event: ControllerEvent? = null): CompletableSubscribeProxy =
    observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .autoDisposable(getScopeProvider(event))
```

Note that the return type is now `CompletableSubscribeProxy` and not `Completable` so the location of the call in the chain might need to be changed.

I create different scopes:

```
    private val scopeProvider: ControllerScopeProvider by lazy { ControllerScopeProvider.from(this) }

    private val destroyScopeProvider: ControllerScopeProvider by lazy {
      ControllerScopeProvider.from(
        this,
        ControllerEvent.DESTROY
      )
    }
...
```

And this is how `getScopeProvider` looks

```
    private fun getScopeProvider(event: ControllerEvent?): ControllerScopeProvider =
    when (event) {
        null -> scopeProvider
        ControllerEvent.DETACH -> detachScopeProvider
        ControllerEvent.DESTROY_VIEW -> destroyViewScopeProvider
        ControllerEvent.DESTROY -> destroyScopeProvider
        else -> throw RuntimeException("Scope for event ${event.name} wasn't created")
    }
```